# Як перекласти українською прикметник "partisan"?

Tags: переклад, from-english

Читаючи політичні новини, часто зустрічається прикметник *partisan*, наприклад:

> […] ***partisan*** attacks on the FBI & DOJ — [джерело](https://www.mccain.senate.gov/public/index.cfm/2018/2/statement-by-sasc-chairman-john-mccain-on-partisan-attacks-on-the-fbi-doj)

За змістом, це слово має два аспекти:

- *«той, що відповідає інтересам однієї політичної партії»* — вузький зміст;
- *«той, що відповідає інтересам певної групи людей, і часто суперечить інтересам інших груп»* — ширший зміст, оскільки *party* — це не завжди політична партія, а може бути просто група людей зі спільними інтересами чи точкою зору.

Також є слово ***bipartisan***, як-то у словосполученні *bipartisan agreement*, яке означає угоду, яка узгоджена між обома партіями.

Вочевидь, слово *партизанський* тут не підходить, бо має значення недержавних збройних загонів у тилу ворога.

Українські словники, на мою думку, дещо зіпсовані термінологічними штампами сусідньої країни, і слово [*партійний*](http://sum.in.ua/s/partijnyj) має явно виражені  конотації, яких я хотів би уникнути при перекладі.

Спробував також розглядати варіант [*однопартійний*](http://sum.in.ua/s/odnopartijnyj), але це більше підходить як означення політичної системи деяких країн, «світочів демократії». :)

Отже, **запитання**: чи є більш влучне слово — можливо навіть, яке б не містило кореня «партія»?

Answer (score 4, accepted):

Можна [вийти](https://ukrainian.meta.stackexchange.com/a/221/585) на синонім слова **adherent**.

[Українсько-англійський словник 1955р. (К. Андрусишин, Я. Крет)](https://e2u.org.ua/s?w=adherent&dicts=8&highlight=on)

Видно, що переважно прикріплюється закінченнями на штиб республіканець, маккейнівець тощо. Але для окремого слова знаходимо таке:

> **односу́м (-ма)**
>   comrade, political friend (adherent); fellow-inmate; accomplice;

Там також инше слово.

> *Окрім перекладу саме прикметника partisan, можна ще спробувати відштовхнутися від значення іменника.*

Саме так, коли згадати, що *party* містить значення *частину*, у той же час наше *сторона* теж маʼ таке значення

> **сторо́нник (-ка)**
>   partisan, adherent, partyman, supporter

Те саме стосується до *бік*, з якого легко отримати існуючого і вже згадане слово у коментарях — *прибічник*.

[Словник української мови: в 11 томах. — Том 7, 1976. — Стор. 559.](http://sum.in.ua/s/prybichnyk)

> Той, хто підтримує, захищає кого-, що-небудь, поділяє чиїсь погляди і т. ін.; послідовник, прихильник. *Я ваш добродій і прибічник, Даю всі вольності* (Володимир Самійленко, I, 1958, 229); *Кореспонденти, недавні прибічники,.. з обуренням ганьбили зрадника* (Іван Франко, VI, 1951, 280); *Природний поділ на прибічників Наливайка й Лободи почався серед старшин* (Іван Ле, Наливайко, 1957, 363); *Є. П. Гребінка виділяється серед українських байкарів першої половини XIX ст. як найбільш яскравий прибічник школи Крилова* (Радянське літературознавство, 1, 1962, 56);

---

Особисто не бачу особливих проблем з *партійний*. Треʼ відмежуватися від виражених забарвлень та перенаправляти на слово *совєт*.

---

Щодо иншого і суперечливого [значення](//en.wiktionary.org/wiki/partisan#Adjective):

> *Adjective* Devoted to or biased in support of a party, group, or cause.

То ніц заважає залишити чи далі бавити з приростками: явно **проти·бічні**, чи посередніше **небез·сторонні**.

[Словник української мови: в 11 томах. — Том 5, 1974. — Стор. 247](http://sum.in.ua/s/nebezstoronnij)

> НЕБЕЗСТОРОННІЙ, я, є. Який виявляє деяку упередженість; упереджений. *Василина Матвіївна завжди має свої гострі небезсторонні думки* (Костянтин Гордієнко, Буян, 1938, 55).

На додачу [синоніми](http://lcorp.ulif.org.ua/dictua/):

> УПЕРЕДЖЕНИЙ (який склався щодо кого-, чого-небудь наперед, до ознайомлення з ним), ТЕНДЕНЦІЙНИЙ, НЕОБ’ЄКТИВНИЙ, НЕБЕЗСТОРОННІЙ. *Упереджене ставлення до когось; Упереджені уявлення; Тенденційний підхід до чого-небудь; Необ'єктивна оцінка;*

Answer (score 6):

На сайті dict.com зустрів переклад [partisan](https://www.dict.com/%D0%B0%D0%BD%D0%B3%D0%BB%D1%96%D0%B8%D1%81%D1%8C%D0%BA%D0%BE-%D1%83%D0%BA%D1%80%D0%B0%D1%96%D0%BD%D1%81%D1%8C%D0%BA%D0%B8%D0%B8/partisan) "упереджений".

Крім того, прикметник partisan [пропонують](https://www.multitran.ru/c/m.exe?CL=1&s=partisan&l1=1) перекладати як "необ'єктивний", "заангажований", "тенденційний", "фанатичний".

Окрім перекладу саме прикметника partisan, можна ще спробувати відштовхнутися від значення іменника.

Згідно з [Українсько-англійським словником](https://e2u.org.ua/s?w=partisan&dicts=all&highlight=on&filter_lines=on) та [slovnenya.com](http://slovnenya.com/dictionary/partisan/interface/Ukr) partisan - це "прихильник", "поборник", "прибічник". Тобто у контексті вашого посилання "partisan attacks" - це напади "співприхильників", "співпоборників" або "співприбічників" Мак Кейна на ФБР та Департамент юстиції.

Зустрічаються ще у Google "співпартійники" та "співпартійці", але у тому ж словнику СУМ є лише "партієць", тобто член комуністичної партії.

(У "Словнику української мови" Б. Грінченка 1909 року [знайшлося](https://r2u.org.ua/s?w=%D1%81%D1%82%D0%BE%D1%80%D0%BE%D0%BD%D0%BD%D0%B8%D0%BA&scope=all&dicts=all&highlight=on) слово "вашенець" - "прихильник вашої партії". Якби це слово використовувалося б досі, можна було б створити "нашенець" - "прихильник нашої партії" і перекласти англійську фразу як "З приводу останніх нападів нашенців на ФБР та Департамент юстиції". Нажаль так ніхто не каже.)

Comment: скажіть, будь ласка, чому ви даєте посилання на російські словники? чому не на польські? чому не на чеські? чому не на словенські? як на мене, недоречність таких посилань є очевидною (будь-якою іншою мовою, як і російською). хочу зрозуміти, чому вона неочевидна вам. ну от не розумію я російську, припустімо, як мені перевірити ваші посилання? як піти й почитати самому? і ні, відсутність в онлайні великих англ-укр словників розпізнаних - не арґумент.

Comment: https://ukrainian.meta.stackexchange.com/q/218/240 зробив питання на меті.

Comment: Запропонуйте якісні англо-українські словники і я буду користуватися ними. Чеську, польську, словенську мову не знаю, хоча отримував відповіді з посиланнями на джерела на цих мовах і намагався зрозуміти про що там йдеться. Якщо вам не подобається ця відповідь - можете допрацювати цю, написати свою, поставити уточнюючі питання. В мене було небагато часу на пошук джерел, може ви можете виділити більше ресурсів на пошуки і створення якіснішою відповіді.

Comment: "вашенець" і "нашенець", імхо, є прикладами [nonce words](https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Nonce_word). На цьому етапі історії їх вже не можна генералізувати, тому що партії вже не називаються виключно за назвами ідеологій, а мають "брендові" назви, які можуть містити, наприклад, слово "наш" (та ж "Наша Україна"), і слово "нашенець" можна зрозуміти як "прибічник "Нашої України"" (зрештою, опоненти НУ іноді вживали слово "нашисти"). Так що все, поїзд пішов )

Comment: До того ж "співприбічники", "співпоборники" і "співприхильники" – таких слов не існує. З усіх них треба видалити "спів-". І у тому контексті йдеться не про прихильників МакКейна. МакКейн закликає всі сторони утриматися від атак на державні структури, мотивованих їхньою вузькою ідеологією.

Comment: @Artemix Не потрібно додавати посилання на російські словники в SE Ukrainian language. Я б рекомендував посилатися, в першу чергу, [на англійські тлумачні словники, які де-факто є стандартами](https://www.listofpopular.com/literature/best-english-dictionary/) (дивись топ списку). Переклад за допомогою таких словників також, де факто, є найкращою практикою(бо найточнішою) практикою перекладу. В другу чергу, на українські, оскільки, об'єктивно, вони досить низькоякісні і оригінальні слова перекладаються дуже часто одним або декількома словами, не рідко з помилками

Answer (score 4):

Це треба перекладати ситуативно-фразово – як "атаки на ФБР і Міністерство юстиції, мотивовані партійними ідеологіями". Ідеться, власне, про критику з вузької позиції кожної з двох партій, і ця критика шкодить інтересам країни як такої.

Тут цей прикметник вживається ***не*** у значенні "of, relating to, or characteristic of a partisan or partisans" ([American Heritage Dictionary](http://thefreedictionary.com/partisan)), а у *другому* значенні:

> biased in support of a party, group, or cause

Саме тому не можна просто перекладати *іменник* partisan і намагатися робити з нього прикметник. Це покриє лише перше значення.

Запропоновані @Artemix'ом слова "тенденційний" і "заангажований" в цілому годяться, але в контексті американської політики, коли вживають "partisan щось", ідеться цілком конкретно про дві головні партії.

Comment: *biased* = *упереджений* — було б гарним варіантом, але мені значення цього слова здається дещо загальним: *упередженість* не обовʼязково означає прихильність до групи, а *partisan* — означає.

Comment: @bytebuster В тому-то і заковика, що biased **≠** упереджений. Це один з можливих, але все-таки неповноцінних еквівалентів. Bias - це одне з тих слів, якому повного еквівалента нема (інші подібні - frustration, insight, to fail to do sth). Коли ми виходимо за межі простих слів на кшталт pencil і telephone, починається сфера, де не вся семантична картина слова в одній мові покриватиметься **одним з** еквівалентів у іншій мові. Тому не існує такої речі, як "переклад цього слова". Існують "варіанти перекладу". Й існує потреба у ситуативному перекладі і перефразуванні.

Comment: @bytebuster Проблема з еквівалентизацією biased і упереджений у тому, що "упереджений" - завжди _проти_ чогось. А bias, якщо розглядати, так би мовити, голий стрижень цього слова, це схильність _у бік_ чогось. Можна сказати "bias in favor" і "bias against", але без оцих прийменників _голий_ сенс це якраз "за". Так що з цього місця проблеми тільки починаються.